# Use user entity with additional data in a jhipster microservice

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices, jhipster

im currently working on a Jhipster project. i have the jhipster uaa set up, to register users(default implementation). now i want to create a userService (jhipster microservice) which acts like an api for user profiles. I already created an userprofile entity which should extend the default user entity. I am also able to assign a user to a userprofile via the gateway (i`m not shure if this is working properly) ,but now i got a few problems/things i dont understand:

1. do i need to create the userprofile entity in the microservice,gateway or both? if i follow the instructions given by the jhipster doc (https://www.jhipster.tech/tips/022_tip_registering_user_with_additional_information.html) i get this error code:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown entity name: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User
```

but i'm not shure if this example is for a microservice usecase. 
This also only happens if i delete the `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`annotation above the id value.

2. do i actually need a seperate userservice to fetch the "extended" user entity (userprofiles)? 
   I´m thinking, that the userservice-api returns the userprofile( which should share the user id with the user entity).
3. I want to add additional fields to the user registration form (username,adress,postalCode,city). is it possible to use this information to create a default user entity, as well as an extended userprofile which is handled by my microservice?

I appreciate any help, since this is a pretty important project. please let me also know, if i got something about the jhipster microservice "mechanics" wrong. I should note, that i'm at beginner level with spring development, so sorry if i'm missing something obvious.

Comment: I should add, that my userprofile entity uses an dto layer. i read somewhere, that this might be a problem because mapping dtos to non-dtos can be troublesome

Comment: Which authentication do you use? Ideally, the extra information should be added to your token claims so that microservices don't have to access the gateway or auth provider for getting them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay, so i figured out a solution. For anyone dealing with this kind of problem: 
I looked again at the solution provided by jhipster: 
https://www.jhipster.tech/tips/022_tip_registering_user_with_additional_information.html

which is a bit outdated, but in general its still working. The problem was, that files moved locations and changed some methods (which i didnt notice earlier), but the principle is still applicable.

Answer (score 0):

I think a DTO would be the most efficient solution. Jhipster already integrates Mapstruct. You create a dto that you pass to your service layer when creating a new user then the mapper does the mapping to have the defaultUser and persist it.
I advise you to read the Mapstruct doc or examples on the Jhipster website, here is the link : https://www.jhipster.tech/using-dtos/

Comment: thanks for answering. I´m using a DTO now. I created a profile entity in the uaa server, which should extend the user entity (one-to-one) using the @MapsId annotation.  Jhipster also created a profileMapper and serviceImpl. for me. if i look at the code everything should work, but if i create a new user, jhipster doesnt safe a new profile entity to my database. am i missing something? do i need do implement this by myself? i assumed this would work "out of the box" since its generated code.